# Unslider Styling Style Issue Dots

Tags: html, css, slider, unslider

I am currently styling the http://unslider.com/ jquery banner.
I want to style the dots to be centered in a rectangle.
When I set the background in the dots class it pulls them out of the center.

I would just wrap a div around them but since there are not referenced in the html I am not sure what to do. I have tried to do this using background but it created issues.
 CSS:
    .banner { width 100% !important;
    height:auto !important;
     position: relative;
     overflow: auto;
           }

```
.dots {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height:3vw;
  width:7vw;
  padding-top:1vw;

}

.dots li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  text-indent: -999em;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background:#e8e8e9;
  -webkit-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
  -moz-transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
  transition: background .5s, opacity .5s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="banner">
    <ul>
        <li><div class ="image-container"><img src="images_slider/slide1.jpg" alt="Slide1" width="1920" height="500">
        <a href="#"><img class="leftbtn hvr-grow" alt="" src="images_slider/learnmore.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="rightbtn  hvr-grow" alt="" src="images_slider/catalog.png"></a></div>
        </li>
        <li><div class ="image-container"><img src="images_slider/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide2" width="1920" height="500">
         <a href="#"><img class="leftbtn  hvr-grow" alt="" src="images_slider/contact.png"></a></div>
        </li>
        <li><div class ="image-container"><img src="images_slider/slide3.jpg" alt="Slide3" width="1920" height="500">
        <a href="#"><img class="leftbtn  hvr-grow" alt="" src="images_slider/learnmore.png"></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="rightbtn  hvr-grow" alt="" src="#"></a></div>
        </li>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: html code of the slider? Without the html code its difficult to help

Comment: @JavierGonzalez fixed :)

Comment: I dont see the code for the dots, unslider places the dots already in the center, they use in the css code for the dots: nav.unslider-nav, nav.unslider-nav ol, nav.unslider-nav ol li

Comment: Sorry my mistake, they place the html code for dots automatically, as I said before they use nav.unslider-nav and nav.unslider-nav ol and nav.unslider-nav ol li in there css code for the dots

Comment: When I use those selectors to try and force some more centering I am getting no change. Right now the list is centering the first list element, not the entire list itself. I am not sure why this is happening because I have the list inline-block and text-align: center on the parent. :(

Comment: Also I notice when I remove the width from the class .dots it is perfectly centered but I don't need 100% width of the slider. Maybe if I could find an alternative to width to get that background cut off that would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments the dots are already centered in unslider, you dont have to add a class to the dots. If you want to make a centered rectangle of the dots navigation under the slider, you only need this in your css-code:

```
nav.unslider-nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

**margin: 0 auto;** centers the dots navigation if not 100%
change **width:;** as you like
 the other selectors to use in your css-code to change dots as you like are:

```
nav.unslider-nav ol 
nav.unslider-nav ol li
nav.unslider-nav ol li.unslider-active
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out something in the unslider code was inserting padding and large border around the dots causing funky behavior. I set them all to zero and the centering is now fine.